# How to find the Request URL from a webpage in chromes's Inspect Element> Network > XHR > Response > Headers > General

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, xmlhttprequest

Sorry if I don't know the correct terminology, I'm new to web scraping, please correct my terminology if you feel like it.

I'm working on a project to scrape images off all the pieces by an artist given the URL for the artist's gallery. What I am doing is finding the unique id of each page of the gallery that will lead me to the webpage hosting the original image. I can already scrape from the art page I just need the id's of each page from gallery.

Artist Gallery --> Art Page --> scrape image

The id's of each page on the gallery page is not available in the page source, since it is being loaded in separately through JavaScript I think, so I can not grab them using:

```
import requests
import urllib.request


response = requests.get(pageurl)
print(response.text)
```

But I have found that by going to Chrome Inspect Element> Network > XHR > Response > Headers > General, there is a request URL that has all the id's that I need, and below that is a Query String Parameters section that has all the id's I need.
[Picture of Query String Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUdqb.png)

[Picture of Request URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odjmd.png)

I am using BeautifulSoup, but the problem just lies with how to get the data.
I have also used `urllib.request.urlopen(pageurl)` with similar results. I have also tried Selenium, but was still unable to get the ids, although I may not have done so correctly, I was able to get to the webpage, but maybe I did not use the right method. For now, this is what I want to try. EDIT: I have since figured it out using Selenium. (I just wasn't trying hard enough), but would still like some input regarding intercepting XHR's.

[Link to site if you really want to see it, but you may have to login](https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?id=11764388&type=illust)

Comment: You're talking about intercepting the xhrs and you would need javascript for this.

Comment: Okay, so I guess Selenium is the only way to go?

Comment: More like puppeteer. Python is not your friend for this one.

Comment: Did you ever manage to scrape the URLs through Element> Network > XHR? If you did I'd like to know how you did it please :)