# How to get the XHR URLs in inspect->networks using Python?

Tags: python

When I access a website, how can I use Python to get all the links from Right-Click -> Inspect -> Network -> XHR ?

I looked at multiple threads on stackoverflow, without any luck.

Using Selenium I build an algorithm to fill out multiple formulas on https://forsikringsguiden.dk/, that gets me to a page with an overview of insurance prices. From here I need to get all the XHRs following the above path of inspecting, especially this one: https://forsikringsguiden.dk/signalr/poll?transport=longPolling&messageId=d-93E0B6D2-A%2C0%7CO7%2C0%7CO8%2C1%7CO9%2C0&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=zDfK1T3tEpZFcC%2FMFDN3lzzspSq8GPKgit99GJtaJlfcU8n0q%2BnRyMR3XTMMq9rNMitppogK2OOlA8xXUjnZJz9sW1PPC4u4Nr5s4O1zKDRl4K0u3O%2Bvh3AyHIfh8WFx&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22insuranceofferrequesthub%22%7D%5D&tid=10&_=1574085414055

I thought of finding the connectionToken somewhere else on the site, and fetching that and inserting, and slowly building up the URL piece by piece, but I cannot find the connectionToken anywhere else besides the XHRs.

I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56616009/python-how-to-find-the-request-url-from-a-webpage-in-chromess-inspect-element) that I might need something else besides Python with this problem?

I'm thinking below code is the beginning of it, but I'm not sure.

```
response = requests.get(pageurl)
print(response.text)
```

I looked into using javascript in Spyder python interface, but I'm not sure it's possible.